# mongoose remove error: remove is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I can select a document like this:

```
const Card = await db.SessionCard.findById(cardID);
```

Then I want to remove the `Card` like this:

```
await Card.remove();
```

But I get this error:

> TypeError: Card.remove is not a function

How can I fix this?

mongoose version: 7.3.1

Answer (score 2):

I think you want .deleteOne(), .remove() doesn't seem to exist on their website. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting that way, you can simply call a single function like this:

```
await db.SessionCard.findOneAndDelete({ _id: id })
```